# Best way of storing an array in an SQL database?

Tags: sql, arrays, sqlite, database-design

For an Android Launcher (Home Screen) app project i want to implement a feature called "Sort by usage". This will sort by the launch count of an app within a user settable timeframe.

The current idea for the implementation is to store an array of unich epoch timestamps, one for each launch.
Additionaly it'll store a counter caching the current amount of launches within the selected timeframe, incremented with every launch. Of course, this would regularly have to be rebuild as time passes, but merely every few hours or at least x percent of the selected timeframe, so computations definitely wouldn't run as often as without the counter, since this information is required everytime when any app entries on screen need to get sorted - but i'm not quite sure if it matters in any way during actual use.

I am now unsure how to store the timestamp array inside the SQL database. As there is a table holding one record with information about each launcher entry i thought about the following options:

- Store the array of unix epochs in serialized form (maybe JSON Array) to one field of the entries record
- Create a seperate table for launch times with
  a. each record starting with an id associated with an entry followed by all launch times, one for each field
  b. each record a combination of entry id and one launch time
  these options would obvously have the advatage of storing the timestamp using an appropriate type

Comment: The **one thing** that any database has to hold "any number of items" is a **table** ...

Comment: @marc_s Yes! But still: Would option b. or option a. be the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

I probably didn't quite understand why you need a second piece of data for your launch counter - the fact you saved a timestamp already means a launch - why not just count timestamps? Less updating, less record locking, more concurrency.

Now, let's say you've got a separate table with timestamps in a classic one to many setting. 
**Pros** of this setup - you never need to update anything - just keep inserting. You can easily cluster your table by timestamp, run a filter on your timeframe and issue a group by and count rows. The client then will get the numbers and sort by count (I believe it's generally better to not sort in SQL). **Cons** - you need a join to parent table and probably need to get your indexes right.

Alternatively you store timestamps in a blob text (JSON, CSV, whatever) with your main records. This definitely means you'll have to update your records a lot, which potentially opens you up to locking issues. Then, I'm not entirely sure what you'll have to do to get your final launch counts - you read all entities, deserialise all timestamps, filter by timeframe and then count? It does feel a bit more convoluted in your case.

I don't think there's such thing as a "best" way. You have to consider pros and cons. From what I gather, you might be better off with classic SQL approach unless there's something I didn't catch that will outweigh my points above